# Why I obtain this "Unable to access jarfile" error when I try to execute my jar?

Tags: java, jar, jvm, executable-jar

I have the following problem trying to execute a jar file (created from my project) into the Windows shell (the DOS prompt).

I have a file named **Main.jar**. If I unzip this file it contains a **mainPkg** folder (that is the name of the package containing the **Main** class that itself contains the **main()** method).

So into the **mainPkg** folder there is the **Main.class** file that contains the **main()** method.

Ok so, from the shell, I go into the directory that contains the **Main.jar** and I perform:

```
C:\Projects\edi-sta\build\jar>java -jar mainPkg.Main.jar
Error: Unable to access jarfile mainPkg.Main.jar
```

But as you can see I obtain the **Unable to access jarfile mainPkg.Main.jar**. Why? What am I missing? How can I solve this issue and execute my **Main.jar** file?

Comment: I do not understand your problem in detail. But try to use `java -jar Main.jar`

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does "Could not find or load main class" mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18093928/what-does-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-mean)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18093928/what-does-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-mean

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically you've two types of JARs

- Normal JAR - to package your classes into a single archive
- Runnable JAR - This is similar to Normal jar except that you can run this with `java -jar` command like this `java -jar RunnableMain.jar`.
  In this one we already configure the class having main(),so no need to pass the class name in jar command

Assuming that yours is a normal JAR, you can execute your class of interest like this

```
C:\Users\arkantos\work>java -classpath C:\Project\Main.jar mainPkg.Main
```

Notice that i've mentioned the absolute path of the JAR to add it to classpath, because I'm in a different directory, if not you can cd to that dir containing your `Main.jar` and then invoke your Main class like this

```
C:\Project>java -classpath Main.jar mainPkg.Main
```

Here `Main.jar` is inside Project directory so no need to give absolute path

Comment: Tnx, only a doubt. For runnable JAR do you mean a normal JAR in which I declare a manifest file in wich I declare what is my main class?

Comment: Exactly.. You can do that manually or eclipse has an export as Runnable JAR option

Comment: Try using some IDE like eclipse / NetBeans / IntelliJ.. Things will be much better :-)

Comment: I am using IntelliJ to develop, I only manually create my manifest file :-)

Answer (score 3):

The syntax for executing a class containing a main method in a jar is:

```
java -classpath <jarFile> <class>
```

In your case:

```
java -classpath Main.jar mainPkg.Main
```

If you want to execute the jar using `java -jar` you must create an executable jar file. That can be done in different ways depending on which build tools you use.

Comment: Performing java -classpath Main.jar mainPkg.Main now I obtain this error: "impossible to find or load main class". Why? :-(

Comment: Good question, that should work. The error message means that class cannot be found, so either the path to the jar file is wrong or the class name is wrong.

Comment: I bet it says "could not", not "impossible to". It's important to quote error messages exactly. But see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18093928/what-does-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-mean

Comment: I am trying to perform the java -classpath Main.jar mainPkg.Main from the directory that contains the jar file. So it should be right !!! And into the Main.jar file I have the mainPkg directory that contains Main.class file so what is wrong?